# Data input: Expanding or Sliding Windows for LSTMs?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, validation, lstm

External research [R1](https://alphascientist.com/walk_forward_model_building.html) (*Stock Prediction with ML: Walk-forward Modeling by Chad Gray on 18/07/2018 at alphascientist.com*) led me to believe that a sliding window is
more favourable than an expanding window but this was on Linear
Regression, does this still hold true for LSTMs?

By more favourable, I mean that according to the link, this method allowed the model to apply some time based relevance to features. *i.e* in the distant past some features were impactful but less so in more recent data, and the model was able to distinguish this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run some cross validation (or better yet, some **nested** cross validation) and treat this difference as a hyperparameter?

As in, just include another parameter in your tuning, which is a 0/1 "expanding/sliding window" and try both to see which gives better performance?

My intuition would be that for a data-hungry method like LTSM, you would want to give it all the info you can and use an expanding window, but try both and see!

Personal tip: I would advise against using neural nets for financial prediction. You probably have too little data for a neural network to be properly optimized (too little data, too many parameters to optimize).

Comment: Thanks for feedback. What would you recommend instead? Also how much would be enough? At the moment I work with 3 years of minute data over 10 pairs.

Comment: Also I've clearly misunderstood something. I thought expanding or sliding windows were two options of nested cross validation?

Comment: @Panda Ah! That seems like a good amount of data, then. I'm a bit confused by your confusion :P In your question, you were asking whether you should train your LTSM model on a sliding or expanding window of data, right? I suggest you just try both and see what's better! When we're talking about nested cross validation, for time series data, it's typically done with the outer loop as an expanding window with a fixed size test set in front of it.